# Convert integer to text in SQLite's SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, type-conversion

I would like to create a SELECT query that would return numbers from column in `integer` format as a `text` format - can I do it in SQLite?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

SQLite supports [CAST](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) and:

> Casting an INTEGER or REAL value into TEXT renders the value as if via sqlite3_snprintf() except that the resulting TEXT uses the encoding of the database connection.

So you can do things like this:

```
select cast(some_integer_column as text) from some_table;
```

Or, depending on what you're trying to do, you could just treat the numbers as strings and let SQLite coerce the types as it sees fit:

```
select some_int || ' pancakes' from some_table;
select some_int || '' from some_table;
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, the official documentation consistently gets the syntax wrong as `CAST(<expr> TO <type>)` (note the *TO* in there).

Comment: @Martijn: I didn't even notice that in the docs as I'm used to the standard *as* syntax. How many times does the official documentation list the full CAST syntax? I only see one mention but I guess that counts as consistent :)

Comment: The syntax diagram is correct, but the changelog for 2.8.2 also uses the wrong syntax. 2 out of 3 uses on the whole site that spell out the syntax are wrong though; but I may have exaggerated a little. :-) I reported it to the project.

Comment: Seems that `CAST(... TO ...)` doesn't work, but `AS` does?  At least as of the writing of this comment.

Comment: @Brad Looks like the `cast(... to ...)` was a typo in the documentation at some point. The "CAST expressions" docs (currently) use AS, the syntax diagram uses AS, the SQL standard uses AS, and AS even works :)