# Coerce dbGetQuery to produce strings

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have a SQL database with two tables.  In one all of the data is stored as TEXT, while the other stores columns as TEXT, DOUBLE, TIME, INT, DATE, etc.  (I checked using `dbDataType(ANSI(), data)`)  When I try to join the two in R, though, I get the following warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) : Column `7.Preferred.Food`: mixed type, first seen values of type integer, coercing other values of type string
```

When I check the structure of the output dataframe, column 7.Preferred.Food is an integer.  The problem is, I want my data imported as a string.  Is there a way to compel dbGetQuery to produce only characters?  My code is below:

```
breed= dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from foster
                     inner join pets
                     on `ID` = `TAG`')
```

Preferred Food is an integer in `pets` but not in `foster`, but switching the order has no effect.

I've tried:

```
dbExecute(con, "ALTER TABLE file ALTER COLUMN 7.Preferred.Food TEXT")
```

and got

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "ALTER": syntax error
```

and

```
update_query <- paste("update pets",
                      "ALTER COLUMN 7.Preferred.Food TEXT")
dbSendQuery(con, update_query)
```

and got

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "ALTER": syntax error
```

Edit: For work restrictions, I'm stuck with RSQLite and DBI (and the tidyverse); I can't use the whole plethora of extra SQL tools in R.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is very specific, one column in a table can contain values of mixed type. The example below recreates result sets with mixed types:

```r
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS id UNION SELECT 'q', 2 ORDER BY id")
#> Warning in result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n): Column `a`: mixed type, first seen
#> values of type integer, coercing other values of type string
#>   a id
#> 1 1  1
#> 2 0  2
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT 'q' AS a, 1 AS id UNION SELECT 1, 2 ORDER BY id")
#> Warning in result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n): Column `a`: mixed type, first seen
#> values of type string, coercing other values of type integer
#>   a id
#> 1 q  1
#> 2 1  2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Use the SQL `CAST(... AS ...)` to coerce to a string and do more fine-grained processing in R:

```r
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())
dbGetQuery(
  con,
  "
  WITH tbl AS (SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS id UNION SELECT 'q', 2 ORDER BY id)
  SELECT CAST(a AS text) AS typed_a, id 
  FROM tbl
  "
)
#>   typed_a id
#> 1       1  1
#> 2       q  2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

See [Convert integer to text in SQLite's SELECT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12419693/946850) for more detail.