# Converting mixed type column in RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have an issue with a mixed type column in a database using RSQLite. When I query the database using `dbGetQuery`, it seems to coerce strings to numeric producing NAs. It gives the following warning message: “mixed type, first seen values of type real, coercing other values of type string”. The column has been declared as `VARCHAR`. I tried to use `CAST AS` as in `dbGetQuery(con, ‘SELECT CAST(problematic_column_name AS TEXT) FROM tbl’)`
but that didn’t do the trick. Am I using `CAST AS` incorrectly or is there another way of forcing `dbGetQuery` to convert the column to text? Or should I be using an entirely differnt approach for fixing this issue?

Update:
I pass the result of my original query to an R data frame as in:

```
result <- dbGetQuery(con, ‘SELECT problematic_column_name FROM tbl’)`
```

The idea to use `CAST AS` came from this post: [stackoverflow.com/q/64655954/2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64655954/2554330). But when I pass `dbGetQuery(con, ‘SELECT CAST(problematic_column_name AS TEXT) FROM tbl’)`, I still get the same issue with NAs being rendered although noo warning message is displayed.

Comment: `but that didn’t do the trick` ... what happened when you cast the column to `TEXT` ?

Comment: Converting from VARCHAR to TEXT shouldn't change anything (variable length characters are text).  Who is throwing the error?  The database?  dbGetQuery?  Are you passing the resultset immediately to an R function via a %>% type pipe and that function is raising the error?

Comment: I think this may be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64655954/2554330, but you don't give enough code to be sure.  Are you joining two tables in the query?  If so, you need to do the cast before joining, not after.